# Is there a way to find file-line where the key was bound

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

I am new in Emacs and doing a lot of configuration, I am struggling with finding where the key was bound, for example, my `tab` is bound to `evil-jump-forward` but I grepped the all packages and my configs and I still cannot find it? Is there some emacs command to find out a file-line information about the key binding?

Comment: for your specific case, evil uses a macro `evil-define-motion`, so you would need to grep for `evil-define-motion evil-jump-forward`

Comment: @jenesaisquoi: I think the info from your deleted answer and its comments can be helpful in connection with this question. It also makes the question more useful for others. Please consider undeleting it and incorporating the comments, as a way of providing some background information that partially answers the question (as in "you can't just... because...").

Comment: @Drew I think the OP already knew the things I mentioned, and upon re-reading the title, I think my suggestions aren't that useful. I don't know enough details of the keymap implementations, but I was just guessing that they don't keep any information about the file and location of key definitions.

Comment: @Yuki If I grep for `evil-jump-forward` I get several hits, including `(define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "C-i") 'evil-jump-forward))` in `evil-maps.el`.  Do you not see the same?